# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Address'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Created two tables namely Address and Employee.With relationship employee has a n address. The DB script as below.

```
create table address(addressid int,city varchar(10),pincode varchar(10));

insert into address(addressid,city,pincode) values(201,'Hosur',635109);

create table employee(empid int , firstname varchar(20),lastname varchar(20),department varchar(10),emailAddress varchar(50),baseLocation varchar(20),address int,FOREIGN KEY (Address) REFERENCES Address(addressId));
```

But I get the following error while trying to create the employee table:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
>   'Address' 0.117 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add a primary key on addressid in the Address table, this will create the index needed. In your current script there is no guarantee that addressid will be unique, hence if there would be duplicates a foreign key could never determine which row to refer to.

```
create table address(addressId int primary key not null, city varchar(10), pincode varchar(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

because foreign key references primary key.
you don't have primary key in table address.

like this,

```
create table address(addressid int primary key,city varchar(10),pincode varchar(10));

create table employee(empid int , firstname varchar(20),lastname varchar(20),department varchar(10),emailAddress varchar(50),baseLocation varchar(20),address int ,FOREIGN KEY (address) REFERENCES address(addressid));

insert into address(addressid,city,pincode) values(201,'Hosur',635109);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the primary key constraint in the address table, inorder to add foreign key references in employee table

try with the following code:

```
create table address(addressid int primary key not null,city varchar(10),pincode varchar(10));

insert into address(addressid,city,pincode) values(201,'Hosur',635109);

create table employee(empid int , firstname varchar(20),lastname varchar(20),department varchar(10),emailAddress varchar(50),baseLocation varchar(20),address int,FOREIGN KEY  (address) REFERENCES address(addressid));
```